# How to confirm that delete on a struct really works?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find out how to recursively delete objects and confirm that they are successfully deleted, with no memory leaks.

For this purpose I made an example with a linked list node with a userdata struct. I create one of such a node and assign some values.

Now the problem is that delete doesn't seem to work on the node. I expect to read garbage after the delete, but I still get the same data that was there before the delete. I've added a destructor that prints a message so you can see if it is called. How is it possible that the destructor is called, but the data is still there?

It does seem to have something to do with the node containing pointers of its own type, because if I comment out the pointers in the node definition, the data content in the node is deleted as expected (I get garbage values).

```
#include<iostream>

struct userdata{
  int id;
  double d;

  userdata(){}
  ~userdata(){
    std::cout<<"deleting userdata\n";
  }
};

struct node_t{
  node_t* prev;
  node_t* next; 
  userdata data;

  node_t(){}
  ~node_t(){
    std::cout<<"deleting node_t\n";
  }
};

using namespace std;

int main(){

  node_t* ptr = new node_t;
  ptr->data.id = 19;
  ptr->data.d = 3.14159; // pi

  cout<<ptr<<endl;
  cout<<"data.id: "<<ptr->data.id<<", data.d: "<<data.d<<"\n";

  delete ptr; // I expected this to turn the data into garbage.

  // Reading after delete gives me the same results as before!
  cout<<ptr<<endl;
  cout<<"data.id: "<<ptr->data.id<<", data.d: "<<data.d<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xc61530
data.id: 19, data.d: 3.141590
deleting node_t
deleting userdata
0xc61530
data.id: 19, data.d: 3.141590
```

EDIT: It seems like it works as intended, but my expectation didn't match the implementation. Apparently the result of delete can be that the memory at the location isn't changed.

Some have said I'm not supposed to access memory after delete, but that sounds to me like a copout: if there's a problem or something unexpected, just look the other way, just ignore it, problem solved.

It still doesn't sit well with me that I just have to assume it works, without being able to really confirm whether the delete was successful.

For all I know, the delete function may as well be implemented as a no-op, a function that does nothing, and I wouldn't be able to tell the difference from observing my program's behavior! I just want to be certain that my program has no leaks.

> It does seem to have something to do with the node containing pointers of its own type, because if I comment out the pointers in the node definition, the data content in the node is deleted as expected.

In hindsight this was because read after free is undefined behavior. When you have undefined behavior, a small change that seems unrelated but slightly changes the binary, can result in the undefined behavior doing something else than in the previous build.

Comment: It's undefined behavior to access data that is out of scope

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in C++ you don't have to do the `typedef struct ... struct_ name;` dance. That's a C thing. C++ handles struct names differently.

Comment: `~box_t` doesn't delete `box_t::ptr1` or `box_t::ptr2`. You don't assign anything to them in your calling code, but if you did and expected destroying a `box_t` to delete the `box_t`s it points to, you'd expect incorrectly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pointers inside `box_t`. It's a common beginner's expectation that deleting a pointer overwrites what it points at, but that's not the case. Whatever was there is still there, until the freed memory gets reused. Looking at it through the deleted pointer produces undefined behavior, that is, the language definition does not tell you what that code should do.

Comment: "*I still get the same data that was there before the delete.*" An access after a delete is a *bug*. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: A trick you can use to avoid this undefined behavior is to set the dangling pointer to `nullptr` right after you `delete` it. Change `delete ptr;` to `delete ptr; ptr = nullptr;`

Comment: Also consider using [Smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @Camwin, setting the pointer to NULL doesn't mean the underlying data is actually deleted, it just stops you from looking at it. I don't like the religious mindset of 'don't scrutinize, just believe'.

Comment: @qwertyuiop Yes, and the only problem OP had was looking at a deleted pointer. If they wanted to check if the memory was deallocated they should use a debugger or not allocate memory manually.

Comment: @Camwin, looking at a deleted pointer isn't the problem. It's how I thought I could check. It's like you request a company to demolish your house, and when they say they're done, you look at the address and the house is still there. Then when you ask for explanation, someone says "well you shouldn't have checked the address".

So there's no way to check from within the application itself whether the memory was deallocated?

Comment: If your goal is to verify that your program has no leaks, then running your program under `valgrind` or similar is a good way to achieve that.  (Or alternatively you could have the constructors of your class increment a global (possibly atomic) counter, and have class's destructor decrement it, and then at the end of main(), check that the counter's final value is zero)

Answer (score 0):

Reading data from deallocated is undefined behaviour. Undefined means anything can happen including nothing.

In practice when you delete memory, the heap just marks the cell as available. This means some other object can gain a reference to that memory and it is only at that point that the memory will get written to.

Debug heaps may overwrite with garbage to help you the programmer but release heaps do not due to the performance cost.

Comment: Isn't a "debig" heap just a "liddle" heap? (Sorry, I love playing with typos)

Comment: Pay special attention to that last paragraph. This is one of the ways Undefined Behaviour can actually help you: An implementation can check for and do something about what would otherwise be a hidden bug. Since the behaviour is undefined, an implementation is allowed to do something useful.

Comment: Then how can I check that the delete actually did what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Testing. You have to trust (but verify) the compiler and runtime implement `delete` correctly. And you also have to be sure that your destructors are written correctly (along with any [copy and move semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)). Only way to be sure of anything in a program is testing. Taking off and nuking the entire site from orbit is known to work for a great many things, but software ain't one of them.

Comment: Also remember that you could have TWO pointers to the same allocation. There is no back channel in a pointer, it just knows where something is, so if you delete pointer 1, pointer 2 will be "Dangling" and there's no way for it to know.  [Smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-160) can help deal with this in some cases.